# Difficult grep. How can I isolate this number?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, numeric-data

I have this file content:

```
  63 41,3,11,12 
  1 31,60,72,96 
  7 41,3,31,14,15,68,59,60 
  7 60,72,96 
  7 60 
  1 41,3,31,31,14,15,68,59,60 
  60 41,3,115,12,13,66,96 
  1 41,3,11,12,13,66,96
```

I need to grep the '7' before the '60' (where the '60' is not followed by '72,96').

Comment: can something else follow the 60?

Comment: Yes, like in the previous line, the 60 is followed by ,72,96 . But it could be other numbers.

Comment: please add what you tried to solve this.. what should be output for `3 601`, `2 60,72,962` and `5 60,3`? also, what is your grep version, is it GNU grep with `-P` option available?

Comment: are there really leading and trailing spaces in your file?

Comment: Yes, there are leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: Don't know how to check my grep version, but grep -P seem to work (does not show any error). My grep is from bash at Debian 9.

Comment: The output for 3 601, 2 60,72,962 and 5 60,3 should be empty. I need the number that leads the line with just a '60'.

Comment: that seems like you want to match a line that has only two numbers separated by spaces and the second number should be `60`... if so, print the first number of such a line.. please correct and provide example if this summary is wrong

Comment: The summary is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modified sample based on comments

```
$ cat ip.txt
  7 60,72,96 
  7 60 
3 601
 2 60,72,962
5 60,3
43 60   
3 52360

$ grep -oP '^\h*\K\d+(?=\h+60\h*$)' ip.txt 
7
43
```

- `-oP` print only matching portion, uses PCRE
- `^\h*\K` ignore starting blank characters of line
- `\d+` the number to be printed
- `(?=\h+60\h*$)` only if it is followed by blank characters, then `60` and then optional blanks until end of line

Or, just use `awk` for field based processing ;)

Answer (score 4):

Taking just the first field off the lines where the second field is exactly `60` (should work with any awk, not just GNU awk):

```
awk '$2 == "60" {print $1}' < file
```

Or with `grep` and `sed`:

```
grep -E '^[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+60[[:space:]]*$' < file |
   sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]].*//'
```

---

An ugly-ish one-liner in awk for the general case where you want lines with `60` but to exclude exactly the ones that also have the pair `72,96`:

```
awk 'function f(n) { return ($2 ~ "(^|,)" n "(,|$)") }
     f(60) && ! (f(72) && f(96)) {print NR, $1}' < file
```

The function `f(n)` checks if `n` is within the list of numbers in the second field (assuming numbers are separated with commas or beginning/end of field). Then we just check that `60` is present, and the pair `72,96` isn't. The output is the line number (`NR`) and the first field, but it's easy to remove the line number if you don't want it.

Comment: Not enough for me: I don't know in advance what combination of numbers can appear after the 60.

I just need the number that leads the line with just a '60'.

Comment: @Uxio, then why didn't you say so in the first place! That's much simpler to do...

Comment: Sorry, didn't know how to approach the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ cat infile
63 41,3,11,12 
  1 31,60,72,96 
  7 41,3,31,14,15,68,59,60 
  7 60,72,96 
  7 60 
  1 41,3,31,31,14,15,68,59,60 
  60 41,3,115,12,13,66,96 
  1 41,3,11,12,13,66,96   7 60,72,96 
  7 60 
3 601
 2 60,72,962
5 60,3
43 60   
3 52360

$ grep -oP '^\s*[0-9]+(?= 60\s*$)' infile
  7
  7
43
```

---

Description:

```
grep -P '^             # grep from start of line
\s*                    # followed by optional spaces
[0-9]+                 # followed by some decimal digits
(?= 60\s*$)            # That have a <space>60<space(s)><end of line>
                       # but do not capture the 60.
' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `awk` to split the second whitespace-delimited field on commas.  If the result of the split field is more than one single value, it's not interesting, otherwise, if it's 60, print the first whitespace-delimited field:

```
awk 'split($2, a, ",") == 1 && $2 == 60 { print $1 }' <file
```

For the example data given, this prints `7`.